# Referencing(copying) earlier text in a markdown.md file

Tags: reference, copy, markdown

In a markdown.md file, Is it possible to reference and copy earlier text in the file?

Lets say you have the following:

```
Some Type Names
-----
Type 1 - Video
Type 2 - Voice / Sound clip
Type 3 - Picture
Type 4 - Photo Booth Strip (3 | 4 | 5 sequential pictures)

Type 1 - Video
---
Type 2 - Voice / Sound clip
---
Type 3 - Picture
---
Type 4 - Photo Booth Strip (3 | 4 | 5 sequential pictures)
---
```

Instead of having to retype the type headers again below, is there a way to reference earlier text and have it generate in the spot you want, similar to how Excel cell referencing works?  This would be beneficial to only have to worry about naming one item once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown does not have variables http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/